# How to use area of sector equation to answer this word problem?

Tags: circles, problem-solving, area

[image: Area of Sector Question]

I am trying to use the area of a sector equation: $$\frac{\text{angle}}{360}  \pi r^2$$

to work out the total area for this question:

What I did:
$$\frac{60}{360} \cdot \frac{22}{7} \cdot \left(\frac{7}{2}\right)^2$$
to work out the area of the first sector but I don't know what to do next or if I am approaching this question properly.

Thank You And Help Is Appreciated

Comment: I find the wording of the text very strange. "[. . .] from a circle with $7cm$ [. . .]" What does this even mean?

Comment: @wgrenard They forgot to add the word "radius".

Comment: Hint. One of the blue pieces is a quarter of the circle. The other is a third.

Answer (score 1):

total blue area is equivalent to $90^\circ+120^\circ = 210^\circ$

So $\frac{210}{360} \times \frac{22}{7} \times \frac{7}2^2 = 22.46 \mathbb{\ sq.cm}$

(assuming 7cm is diameter)